# Backup API - Restored data not visible until restart the app

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I've implemented the Android Backup API for both Marshmallow and pre-Marshmallow devices exactly as described in the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/backup/index.html).
The application successfully backup the desired files and restore them automatically upon install in Android 6.0 virtual device. But on Android 4.4.4 device the restored data is not visible until I restart the application.

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="***" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:backupAgent=".BackupAgent"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backupscheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key"
        android:value="***" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

My BackupAgent.java:

```
public class BackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {

private static final String PREFS_NAME = "user_prefs";
private static final String PREFS_BACKUP_KEY = "prefs";

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    SharedPreferencesBackupHelper prefsHelper = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, PREFS_NAME);
    addHelper(PREFS_BACKUP_KEY, prefsHelper);
}

}
```

Am I missing something?